# ScreenTip Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that

- finds each hyperlink,
- copies the name of the word the hyperlink is embedded in and then makes that the `ScreenTip`

Currently I have to do it for each cell. How do I update every hyperlink in my workbook?

```
Sub ScreenTip()
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(8, 2), Address:="", ScreenTip:=CStr(Cells(8, 2).Value)
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(8, 3), Address:="", ScreenTip:=CStr(Cells(8, 3).Value)
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(8, 4), Address:="", ScreenTip:=CStr(Cells(8, 4).Value)
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(8, 5), Address:="", ScreenTip:=CStr(Cells(8, 5).Value)
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(8, 6), Address:="", ScreenTip:=CStr(Cells(8, 6).Value)
 `..... etc
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loops over all *existing* hyperlinks on the active sheet, and sets their ScreenTip properties

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim hl As Hyperlink

    For Each hl In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
        hl.ScreenTip = CStr(hl.Range.Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How would I get this to apply to the entire workbook?

Answer (score 0):

As per your question:

```
Dim hy As Hyperlink
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each hy In ws.Hyperlinks
        hy.ScreenTip = CStr(hy.Range.Value2)
     Next
Next
```